# How to pass a String parameter in a future method in Flutter on pressed from other screen?

Tags: flutter, methods, future

I want to pass YouTube playlist id to an YouTube API player screen from on pressed method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. If not, do comment below.

## 1. Define the arguments you need to pass

First, define the arguments you need to pass to the new route. In this example, pass two pieces of data: The title of the screen and a message.

To pass both pieces of data, create a class that stores this information.

```
// You can pass any object to the arguments parameter.
// In this example, create a class that contains a customizable
// title and message.
class ScreenArguments {
  final String title;
  final String message;

  ScreenArguments(this.title, this.message);
}
```

## 2. Create a widget that extracts the arguments

Next, create a widget that extracts and displays the title and message from the ScreenArguments. To access the ScreenArguments, use the ModalRoute.of() method. This method returns the current route with the arguments.

```
// A widget that extracts the necessary arguments from the ModalRoute.
class ExtractArgumentsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/extractArguments';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Extract the arguments from the current ModalRoute settings and cast
    // them as ScreenArguments.
    final ScreenArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(args.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(args.message),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Source](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)

Comment: @RAJMOURYA Consider clicking the tick mark next to the answer to mark this question as answered. Cheers!